# Determine third point of triangle when two points and all sides are known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Determine third point of triangle (on a 2D plane) when two points and all sides are known?

```
A = (0,0) 
B = (5,0)
C = (?, ?)
AB = 5
BC = 4
AC = 3
```

Can someone please explain how to go about this? I understand there will be two possible points and would like to arrive at both.

This is what I've worked out but I'm uncertain at this point how correct it is.

```
C.x = (AB² - BC² + AC²) / (2 * AB)
C.y = sqrt(BC² - (B.x - C.x)²) - B.y
```

Thanks!

**Update - Need to turn the answer into a reusable formula, solving for C.x and C.y**

```
known sides AB, BC, AC
known points A(x, y), B(x, y)
unknown points C(x, y)

AC² - BC² = ((Ax - Cx)² + (Ay - Cy)²) - ((Bx - Cx)² + (By - Cy)²)


Goal: 

C.x = ?
C.y = ?
```

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/650578/35416

Comment: Notice that this is a right triangle (because $3^2+4^2=5^2$). Drawing a picture might help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The distance between two points $P(p_1,p_2)$ and $Q(q_1,q_2)$ in the plane is$\sqrt{(q_1-p_1)^2+(q_2-p_2)^2}$.

Let us denote coordinates of $C$ by $(x,y)$. Then the distances between from $C$ to $A$ and from $C$ to $B$ will be
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=3 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=9$$
$$\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}=4\Rightarrow (x-5)^2+y^2=16$$
respectively. Substracting the first equation from the second equation we get
$$(x-5)^2-x^2=7 \Rightarrow x^2-10x+25-x^2=7$$
$$\Rightarrow -10x+25=7 \Rightarrow x=\frac{-18}{-10}=\frac{9}{5}$$
Now if we substitute $x=\frac95$ into one of the above equations we get $y=\pm \frac{12}5$
So we find $(x,y)=(\frac95,\frac{12}{5})$ and $(x',y')=(\frac95,-\frac{12}{5})$.

As you see from the picture these two points are symmetric w.r.t $-x$ axis.

[image]

Comment: I see, can you help me understand how you went from those equations to `(9/5,12/5)`? Possibly showing the formula to solve for both x and y individually? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I edited my post to make it clear for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I have one more question though if you don't mind. Part of what I need to do is create a reusable formula for `x = `(C.x) and `y = `(C.y). I've edited my answer with where I am stuck, any EXTRA :) help is appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: This is already reusable, use distance between two points and you get two equation from there and than solve these equations.I guess you want to write a program for this?

Comment: Ömer yes, I've already got it solved though. Thanks!

Comment: Care to share your final solution for other people having the same question?

Comment: @boom Yes please share! I'm one of those people :p

Comment: I dont get where tis `-5` comes from in the second equation!

Comment: The coordinates of the point B are (5,0) so the distance between C and B will be $\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}=4$

Comment: While a perfect answer to a questions' text, this doesn't answer the generic question in the title and text update.

Comment: The only thing clear about this answer is the picture. Everything else is extremely confusing -1

Answer (score 10):

Given coordinates of $A$ and $B$ and lengths $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ we want to find coordinates of $C$. Let's assume that $A$ is at $(0,0)$ and $B$ is at $(0,\overline{AB})$ i.e. in the $y$-direction. Let's also assume that we know point $C$ is in the positive $x$-direction (there is another solution in the other direction). It should be simple to reduce a more general problem to this case. The solution is then:

$$C_y = \frac {\overline{AB}^2 + \overline{AC}^2 - \overline{BC}^2} {2\overline{AB}}$$

$$C_x = \sqrt{\overline{AC}^2 - {C_y}^2}$$

The derivation of this is given below:

Consider the triangle $ABC$ as two right angle triangles as shown:

[Solution of triangle coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGGBB.jpg)

If we call $C_x$ and $C_y$ the coordinates of $C$, then Pythagoras theorem for each of the two triangles gives:

$(1) \qquad \overline{AC}^2 = {C_y}^2 + {C_x}^2$

$(2) \qquad \overline{BC}^2 = (\overline{AB}-C_y)^2 + {C_x}^2$

Rearranging $(1)$ gives

$(3) \qquad {C_x}^2 = \overline{AC}^2-{C_y}^2$

Substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$ and rearranging gives

$$\overline{BC}^2 = (\overline{AB}-{C_y})^2 + \overline{AC}^2-{C_y}^2 
     = \overline{AB}^2 - 2\overline{AB}\cdot{C_y} + \overline{AC}^2$$

$$C_y = \frac{AB^2 + AC^2 - BC^2}{2\overline{AB}}$$

Since $C_y$ is now known $C_x$ can be found by rearranging $(1)$ to give

$$C_x = \pm \sqrt{\overline{AC}^2 - {C_y}^2}$$

Comment: nice true addressing of "reusable formula", this is how I would do it, except for the choice of the reference system. ;-)

Comment: Maybe I'm an idiot but I can't seem to get the correct answer using this

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution in JavaScript
https://gist.github.com/JulienSansot/d394d210c772a48be067d7e3b856dd1e

```
//a,b,c are the sides of the triangle
function get_third_point_coordinates(a, b, c){
  var result = {x:0,y:0};

  if(a > 0){
    result.x = (c*c - b*b + a*a) / (2*a);
  }

  result.y = Math.sqrt(c*c - result.x*result.x);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Though this solution may be programatically correct, it cannot be accepted as a mathematical solution

Comment: Personally I find the fact this this is written in javascript makes it much easier to understand. However there is no way to feed in the x and y of the first two known points so I don't think this could possible work.

Comment: And what are the coordinates of the first two points?

Comment: Point 1 is {x:0, y:0}.

Point 2 is {x:0.001, y:a}.

The distance between point 1 and point 2 is a.

The distance between point 2 and point 3 is b.

The distance between point 1 and point 3 is c.



get_third_point_coordinates(a,b,c) gives the coordinates of Point 3.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle is Pythagorean.  Since $ab=ch$ the second coordinate of $C$ is $\pm12/5$. From $a^2=cp$ the first coordinate of $C$ is $5/9$  thus there are two solutions.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on the formulas used?

Comment: Of course.  For the first formula note that the area of an Pythagorean triangle is either $ch/2$ or $ab/2$, for the latter refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem

Answer (score 0):

You can not determine unless there is a direction in the graph.

As i see  we have AB,BC,AC. If the way they are written imposes a direction then we see that it is not a directed graph. It would be if the sides would be written AB,BC,CA.

Comment: AB == BA, BC == CB, AC == CA (there will be more than one possible answer)

Comment: yes of course.i just wrote an example:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got:
X = (Ax+Bx)/2 plus or minus [(1/2)*sqrt(3)*sqrt((Bx-Ax)^2+(By-Ay)^2)]/[sqrt((-(Bx-Ax)/(By-Ay)+1)]

Then solve for y using any random formula such as the distance formula (since you have x)

Where (X,Y) = unknowns, and (Ax, Ay) is one vertex, and (Bx, By) is another.

Note the above equation may be wrong, but how I can tell you how I got it:

I found the midpoint and opposite reciprocal slope of the line of the two existing vertexes. Then, I found the height of the triangle, which is always half of the base * sqrt(3) due to basic trigonometry. Then, using the midpoint, I used the distance formula and the point-slope formula squared to set up an equation for X and Y, which simplified into the answer above.

I'm going to test in a program soon. Just putting my process out there to see if it helps you.

Comment: Please this [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to better format your mathematics on MathSE.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a general solution with some R code.

- We need to a system of equations (with two unknowns) that are logically independent.
- The area of a triangle can be computed using the sides (Heron Area) and can also be compared to the area formula using vertices of the triangle.
- The distance formula mentioned above can be used twice (AC and BC) and these equations can be subtracted.
- Understanding the nature of the problem, there will be two solutions: C and C'

```
    heronAreaTriangle = function (AB,BC,AC)
        {
        s = 1/2 * (AB+BC+AC); # semi-perimeter
        Area = sqrt(s * (s-AB) * (s-BC) * (s-AC) );
        Area; # returns Area
        }

    findTrianglePointC = function(AB,BC,AC, x_a,y_a, x_b,y_b)   
        {
        M = matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=2);        

        Area = heronAreaTriangle(AB,BC,AC);
        dy = y_a-y_b; dx = x_a - x_b; dxy = x_a*y_b - y_a * x_b;
        y_c = ( dxy + dy * x_c - 2 * Area ) / dx;
        x_c = ( (BC^2-AC^2) - x_b^2 - y_b^2 + x_a^2 + y_a^2 - 2*dy*y_c) / (2*dx);

        M[1,1]=x_c;
        M[1,2]=y_c;

        y_c = ( dxy + dy * x_c + 2 * Area ) / dx;
        x_c = ( (BC^2-AC^2) - x_b^2 - y_b^2 + x_a^2 + y_a^2 - 2*dy*y_c) / (2*dx);

        M[2,1]=x_c;
        M[2,2]=y_c;

        result = as.data.frame(M);
            colnames(result) = c("c_x","c_y");
            # result;

        list("x_a"=x_a,"y_a"=y_a, "x_b"=x_b,"y_b"=y_b, "AB"=AB,"BC"=BC,"AC"=AC,  "Area"=Area, "result"=result);
        }
```

Usage:

```
findTrianglePointC(AB,BC,AC, x_a,y_a, x_b,y_b);
findTrianglePointC(5,4,3, 0,0, 5,0);  # the example above

result = findTrianglePointC(5,4,3, 0,0, 5,0);
result;
result$result;
result$result[1,];
result$result[2,];
as.numeric(result$result[2,]);

result$result[1,]$c_x;
result$result[1,]$c_y;
```

Output:

```
> findTrianglePointC(5,4,3, 0,0, 5,0);  # the example above
$x_a
[1] 0

$y_a
[1] 0

$x_b
[1] 5

$y_b
[1] 0

$AB
[1] 5

$BC
[1] 4

$AC
[1] 3

$Area
[1] 6

$result
  c_x  c_y
1 1.8  2.4
2 1.8 -2.4
```

The logic is correct, although possible errata may exist (I haven't tried it on several cases).

Sources:

- https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/area.html
- https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html
- [Formula to find the third point of triangle when two points and all sides are known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650578/formula-to-find-the-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-kn)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation
- [Determine third point of triangle when two points and all sides are known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006078/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known?noredirect=1&lq=1)

More verbosity about the logic that is simplified above:

```
determinateAreaTriangle = function (x_a,y_a, x_b,y_b, x_c,y_c)
    {
    # https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/area.html
    # https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html
    M = matrix(c(x_a,y_a,1, x_b,y_b,1, x_c,y_c,1), ncol=3);
    A = abs( 1/2 * det(M) );
    A = abs( 1/2 * (x_b*y_c - x_c*y_b - x_a*y_c + x_c*y_a + x_a*y_b - x_b *y_a ) ); # by-hand computation
    A;  # returns Area
    }



# given points A (x_a,y_a) B (x_b,y_b) and lengths of sides AB, BC, AC
    # find coordinates for C (x_c, y_c) which should return two possible answers
    # geometry of two intersection circles from two vertices of triangle = two solutions

    # heronEquation for area, find numeric value
    Area = heronAreaTriangle(AB,BC,AC);
    # use determinateAreaTriangle as an equation to help solve simultaneous system
    # Area = abs( 1/2 * (x_b*y_c - x_c*y_b - x_a*y_c + x_c*y_a + x_a*y_b - x_b *y_a ) );
    # Area = 1/2 * abs ( x_a*y_b - x_b * y_a + x_c * (y_a-y_b) + y_c * (x_b-x_a) );
    # 2*Area = abs ( x_a*y_b - y_a * x_b  + x_c * (y_a-y_b) - y_c * (x_a - x_b) );


    dy = y_a-y_b; dx = x_a - x_b; dxy = x_a*y_b - y_a * x_b; # deltas of x,y, and innerproduct?

    #2*Area = abs ( dxy  + x_c * (dy) - y_c * (dx) );   

    # y_c = ( dxy + dy * x_c - 2 * Area ) / dx;
    # y_c = ( dxy + dy * x_c + 2 * Area ) / dx;

    # distance formula (circle definition)
    # BC = sqrt( (x_c-x_b)^2 + (y_c-y_b)^2 );
    # BC2 = (x_c-x_b)^2 + (y_c-y_b)^2;  # squared is circle formula?
    # AC = sqrt( (x_c-x_a)^2 + (y_c-y_a)^2 );
    # AC2 = (x_c-x_a)^2 + (y_c-y_a)^2; # squared is circle formula?
    # subtract BC2-AC2
    # BC2-AC2 = x_b^2 + y_b^2 - x_a^2 - y_a^2 + 2*x_c * (x_a - x_b) + 2*y_c* (y_a-y_b);

    # BC2-AC2 = x_b^2 + y_b^2 - x_a^2 - y_a^2 + 2*x_c * (dx) + 2*y_c* (dy);

    # solve for x_c in distance formula (for each y_c)
    # x_c = ( (BC^2-AC^2) - x_b^2 - y_b^2 + x_a^2 + y_a^2 - 2*dy*y_c) / (2*dx);



    # https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html
    # A (-2,2), B (1,5) and C (6,-1) ... maybe C' (-1,13)
    # x_a = -2; y_a = 2; x_b = 1; y_b = 5; x_c = 6; y_c = -1;
    # AB=3*sqrt(2);  BC = sqrt(61); AC=sqrt(73); 

    # https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known
    # A (0,0), B (5,0) and C (9/5,12/5) ... maybe C' (9/5,-12/5)
    # x_a = 0; y_a = 0; x_b = 5; y_b = 0; x_c = 9/5; y_c = 12/5;
    # AB=5;  BC = 4; AC=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep simple things simple.

Recognize the Pythagorean triplet of sides $(3,4,5)$

Vector approach. Coordinates of C : $(x,y)$.

$$ \vec{AC}\cdot \vec{BC} =0 \tag1$$
$$ (xi+yj)\cdot[ (x-5)i+y j=0] \rightarrow  \,x^2+y^2-5 x=0 \tag2$$

This is only *a locus*, and by Thales theorem or should contain both your points at a right angle vertex.

To isolate points of intersection draw a circle of radius $3$ to cut the locus.
$$ x^2+y^2= 3^2 \tag3$$

[image]

Subtracting equations  2) and 3) we get solutions of *quadratic* equation which has *two* real roots.

$$ x= \frac{9}{5}=1.8 \tag4$$

Plug into either of the two equations for example into the second one 3)
$$ y^2= 9- (9/5)^2 = \frac{9\times 16}{25}\rightarrow y= \pm2.4$$

Thus two solution points are 
$$ (1.8,+2.4),\,(1.8,-2.4) \tag5$$

which we can label

$$ C_1, C_2$$