# Formula to find the third point of triangle when two points and all sides are known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I am writing a program in java. I looking for formula to determine the 3rd point in a triangle if the length of all sides and the coordinates of two points  are known.

Comment: Note that in the general case there are $4$ answers.

Comment: To make Andre's comment a bit less elliptical: note that for the purposes of trying to cook up such a 'formula' you can assume, without loss of generality, that the two points you know lie on the x axis. (You may even assume that the origin is their midpoint.) Now try to think about why knowing the lengths doesn't determine the third point uniquely.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/543961/35416

Comment: Do you know *which* side length corresponds to each known point?

Answer (score 1):

Consider what you'd do with ruler and compass. Suppose your two known points are $A$ and $B$, then you'd draw a circle around $A$ with radius $AC$ and a circle around $B$ with radius $BC$. These circles would intersect in two points, either of which would qualify as $C$ unless you know the orientation of the triangle. To replicate this in a program, you have to implement (or find a library to compute) the intersection of two circles.

Since your question is tagged trigonometry, have a look at the [cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). It allows you to compute (the cosine of) an angle given the three lengths of a triangle. So you can know how far along the line $AB$ you have to go, and using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) or [some altitude formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_%28triangle%29#Altitude_in_terms_of_the_sides) you can also compute how far you have to go perpendicular to that line, in order to find $C$.

To be more precise, if $D$ is the point on line $AB$ such that both $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle BDC$ have a right angle at $D$, then the cosine law gives you

\begin{align*}
\lvert AD\rvert &= \frac{\lvert AB\rvert^2+\lvert AC\rvert^2-\lvert BC\rvert^2}
{2\,\lvert AB\rvert} \\
\lvert BD\rvert &= \frac{\lvert AB\rvert^2+\lvert BC\rvert^2-\lvert AC\rvert^2}
{2\,\lvert AB\rvert} \\
\lvert CD\rvert &= \frac{\sqrt{
\left(\lvert AB\rvert + \lvert AC\rvert + \lvert BC\rvert\right)
\left(\lvert AB\rvert + \lvert AC\rvert - \lvert BC\rvert\right)
\left(\lvert AB\rvert - \lvert AC\rvert + \lvert BC\rvert\right)
\left(-\lvert AB\rvert + \lvert AC\rvert + \lvert BC\rvert\right)
}}{2\,\lvert AB\rvert}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heron's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to find the area of your triangle, $T$.

You can use a matrix determinant to find the area in another way:

$$\frac 12 \det \begin{bmatrix} B_x - A_x & C_x - A_x \\ B_y - A_y & C_y - A_y \end{bmatrix} = T$$

That gives you a linear equation between $C_x$ and $C_y$:
$$(A_y - B_y)C_x + (B_x - A_x)C_y = 2 T - A_xB_y + A_yB_x \tag{1}$$

One more equation to fully characterize the system:

$$(A_x - C_x)^2 + (A_y - C_y)^2 = |AC|^2 \tag{2}$$

Solve (1) for $C_x$ (or $C_y$ if you want) and plug that into (2) and solve the resulting quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the two points with known coordinates, and we want to find the coordinates of point $C$.  Since the side lengths are known than if $\theta = \angle CAB$ then

$ \cos(\theta) = \dfrac{ c^2 + b^2 - a^2 }{2 b c} $

Define the unit vector $ u = \dfrac{ B - A }{ c } $

Assuming $ u = (u_x, u_y)$,  define the two unit vectors perpendicular to $u$ as follows

$ v_1 = (- u_y, u_x ) $ and $v_2 = - v_1 = (u_y, -u_x) $

Then we have two possible locations for point $C$, the first one is

$ C = A + b \cos(\theta)  u + b \sin(\theta)  v_1 $

and the second is

$ C = A + b \cos(\theta)  u +  b \sin(\theta)  v_2 $