# Complex numbers and geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, triangles

There exist two different complex numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$, that together with $2+2i, 5+i$ form the vertices of two equilateral triangles. Find the product $c_1c_2$.

Comment: You should say what you tried, or at least what methods you are expected to use.

Comment: How can 4 points form the vertices of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @dfg no, the two given points and c1 OR c2 can make the triangle. The two triangles share the side with the two given points, but they face in different directions.

Comment: @Asimov I see, thanks.

Comment: @dfg, yeah, i can understand your confusion

Answer (score 1):

In the complex plane, this is just a simple geometry problem

So, two points of the triangle are (2,2) and (5,1).

The link below shows how to determine a third point given 2 points and the side lengths Hopefully with it you should be able to figure out the rest. Comment if you get lost so I can advise.

[Determine third point of triangle when two points and all sides are known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known)

Comment: So I got all sides to be sqrt(10). What now?

Comment: Actually, you are right, that isnt a great example. So, do you know how a dot product works? Well, we know all the side lengths, and that they are supposed to be $\sqrt{10}$ long, we you need to pick coordinates so that the dot product is | x|| y| cosθ where x and y are the vectors (one from the given point to the other, and one to the unknown point) cos 60 degrees is 1/2 and $\sqrt{10}*\sqrt{10}=10$, so the dot product has to be 5

Comment: and the dot product can also be computed as $(x_1*x_2)+(y_1*y_2)$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is one vector, and $(x_2,y_2)$ is the other.

Comment: So, what you need to do is find coordinates that make it equal 5,and the two solutions should be your two points (yes, its complicated, but it works)

Comment: So i need to coordinates that make (x1*x2) + (y1*y2) = 5? Do i just guess and check?

Comment: well, one of those (x1,y1) is the vector from one point to the other, or it is <3,-1>. (from point 1 to point 2) the other <x2,y2> is the vector, from point 1, to the corner you are looking for, or one of the unknowns. There should be 2 solutions

Comment: Also, dont guess and check, make a formula, and solve it

Comment: I dont really understand vectors could you explain?

Comment: The use of vectors in geometry is a complete topic. I cant just teach you how to use them in this comment string

Comment: Basically a vector is not a point, but a direction and distance, and they can represent motion, or sides of objects, or energy, or many things